# using png as content in monogame + VS 2013

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mono

I've just started learning to make a 2d-simple game on WP8 (i want to start with mono instead of unity)

i have this code

```
private Texture2D box;
private Texture2D background;

protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);            

        box = Content.Load<Texture2D>("box");
        background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");

        base.LoadContent();
    }
```

and it return error: "The method or operation is not implemented" at the line "box = content..."

follow this tutorial
http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-managing-content
I fount out that i have to install XNA studio and add a contentproject in my solution to convert all content to xnb file.

but since MS have stopped supporting XNA, i don't really want to install a whole platform just to convert some png to xnb . So is there anyway to use png directly in mono project ?

Comment: Last time I checked, no. If the mono team did not develop their own custom content pipeline yet, you have to download XNA, Visual Studio 2010 and process all your content into .xnb. It's well documented on their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go a layer deeper and use SharpDX if you need to but yah no dice. The real pain is that you have to build the XNBs for WP8/Win8 but on iOS you can just use the PNGs, so you at least have that.

Not to have too much of an aside but if your goal is to make a simple 2d game, I'd probably start with Unity if your looking to not work with XNBs and other overhead that goes along with  MonoGame (not by their choice).